# GWT: Static HTML pages should redirect to login.html if not logged in an application

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt

In my application I have some help pages. Those pages can be accessed from app when you log in. But if some one bookmarks them they are still able to access those pages.

What should I write in those static pages so, If someone is not logged in, those pages will redirect to the login.html

Is there a way we can send session variable to HTML page and then use JavaScript to check if the HTML is in session and the redirect to login page.

Comment: Did you mean "bookmarked" or "cached by a browser"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do it would be to use a sevlet filter to intercept requests made to your html pages. If user is logged in, you forward to the html page using `chain.doFilter()`, otherwise you redirect to the login page.

In the example bellow the url pattern is set to `*.html` so it would be called for all html pages living inside the webapp. This means that it would also be called for `login.html` itself, so you would need to add some logic to detect that case (e.g. using `httpReq.getRequestURI()`) and call `chain.doFilter()` in this case, otherwise it would enter an infinite loop. Alternatively, you could give your login page a different extension, like `login.jsp`.

```
@ServletFilter(urlPatterns={"*.html"}) 
public class MyFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
        HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse httpRes = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = httpReq.getSession();

        boolean isLoggedIn = <Your code to check if user is logged in>

        if (isLoggedIn) { 
            // User logged in, forward to html page
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            // User not logged in, redirect to login page
            httpRes.sendRedirect("/login.html");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this method as well ans see if it works for me. Thanks David

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two options:

1. Change your html pages into JSP pages. Check the session, return any content you need or redirect to a login page based on session variables.
2. Move these pages inside your app using [GWT ExternalTextResource](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#TextResource). This way you can keep your html files as is and load these pages only when requested from an authorized user from within your app.

Comment: JSP method seems suitable to me for now. I will try that. Thanks